# How to get any inner text from encoding text using PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex

I am looking for a way to get any value using regex. How can I get the value of address "Indonesia" using regex, I want to return the address using regex using PHP. I have tried this code but I made some mistakes. Please help me. Thank you

```
$typoname = '<p>
[Name:Urma Kanti]
[Address:Indonesia]
[Age:17]
</p>';
preg_match('/[Address:[^>]*>(.*)]/', $typoname, $address);
echo $address[1];
```

Comment: `[` and `]` have special meaning in regex, so you need to escape them if you want to match those _literal_ characters.

Comment: How to get the value of address without adding [ ]

Comment: You say you wanted to extract the `Indonesia` part, so why are you trying to match until a `>`?

Comment: Do you have any control over how this data is rendered in the first place? It would make more sense to use a known data structure such as JSON or XML, or use an API service to pull out machine-readable data instead of trying to parse (part of) an HTML document containing some unknown custom data structure.

Comment: _"How to get the value of address without adding [ ]"_ - no one said you should _not_ match the square brackets, I said you need to _escape_ them. `\[Address:(.*)\]` should basically be enough already to get what you want here - https://regex101.com/r/XiyzwF/1

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is close, but you just need to simplify the grouping and remember that square brackets has special meaning when writing regular expressions.

```php
<?php
$typoname = '<p>
[Name:Urma Kanti]
[Address:Indonesia]
[Age:17]
</p>';
preg_match('/\[Address:(.*?)\]/', $typoname, $address);
echo $address[1];
```

Comment: Thanks I figured out already after getting some comments. although thank you for response.